# Method rawQuery cannot be resolved

Tags: android, sqlite

I've created and opened a database connection in my Android application, but from my `MainActivity.java` class, I'm unable to query the database.

My code is

```
SQLiteDatabase _db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(_filePath + dbHandler.DATABASE_NAME, null, 0);

Cursor resultSet = _db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + dbHandler.TABLE_COMPANY);
```

But I'm being given an error of

> Cannot resolve method 'rawQuery(java.lang.string)'

I've used the `import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` and `database.cursor` imports at the top of the class, so I'm not sure why this isn't working?

Comment: *Is it not possible to query a database from the MainActivity class?* ... no, it's compile time error and it means that **there is no `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery` method which takes only 1(String) parameter**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rawQuery` needs another parameter also . In case you  have no `Where` clause just do this :

```
Cursor resultSet = _db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + dbHandler.TABLE_COMPANY , null);
```

or :

```
Cursor resultSet = _db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + dbHandler.TABLE_COMPANY , new String[]{});
```